Problems with Ellipitc curve implementration SAFE
I'm currently trying to implement the SAFE Protocol by Kochhar in Javascript. (https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-031-24367-7_29)
I'm following the formulas in the paper, but I don't get the correct results. The Paper explains the first step like this:

In this step, each device is presented with an identity, a secret key and a public value. This is an identity-based approach. For Elliptic Curve Key Establishment, a suitable safe elliptic curve $E$ over a finite field along with an initial generator point $G$ of prime order $q$ is chosen by the Key Generation Center. A cryptographic hash function $H: \{0,1\}^* \to \{1,\ldots,q − 1\}$ like HMAC is further needed. The authors of [18] propose a single Key Generation Centre (KGC) for endowing all D2D participants with a secret key and public value. The KGC generates a random number $d \in \{1,\ldots,q−1\}$ as the master private key of itself and computes its own master public key $R$ as $R = d × G$. All D2D participants are aware of the elliptic curve, the point $G$ selected, $R$ and the prime order $q$.
Let us consider two devices A and B want to participate in D2D communication. Before the D2D device is deployed, it is presented with a secret key and public value by the KGC setup. Firstly, the KGC generates a random number $h_A\in \{1,\ldots,q−1\}$ and calculates $U_A = h_A × G$. $U_A$ is the public value of device A presented to it by KGC.
Then, the private key $x_A\in \{1,\ldots,q−1\}$ of device A is generated by the KGC as follows $x_A =[H(\mathsf{ID}_A,U_A)·h_A +d]\bmod q$.
This public value $U_A$ and secret key $x_A$ are then issued to device A. This key issuing is done for every device interested in D2D communications. On receiving $U_A$ and secret key $x_A$, a device can verify its issued values by checking whether
$$x_A×G=H(\mathsf{ID}_A,U_A)×U_A +R\tag1\label{q1}$$
The value $x_A × G$ is the public key of Device A. It is never used explicitly, however, it is computed from the identification parameters of a node and Key Generation Centre public information.

I have the following code at the moment, but the results in left and right (side of the equation) is still different.
const elliptic = require('elliptic');
const { randBetween } = require('bigint-crypto-utils');
        
generateMasterKey() {
            this.ec = new elliptic.ec('secp256k1'); // Sichere elliptische Kurve
            this.q = this.ec.curve.n; // Primzahl q (Ordnung der Kurve)
            this.g = this.ec.curve.g; // Generatorpunkt G

            this.masterPrivateKey = randBetween(BigInt(this.q.toString(10)), BigInt(1));
            this.r_masterPublic = this.g.mul(this.masterPrivateKey); 
        }
    
         
testKey(){
     const h_A = randBetween(BigInt(this.q.toString(10) -1), BigInt(1)); 
     const U_A = this.g.mul(h_A);
     const hashInput = deviceID + U_A.getX().toString(16).padStart(64, '0') + U_A.getY().toString(16).padStart(64, '0');

     const hashHex = CryptoJS.SHA256(hashInput).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
     let h_BigInt = BigInt('0x' + hashHex) 
     const x_A = (h_BigInt * h_A + masterPrivateKey) % BigInt(this.q);

     // x_A * G
     const left = this.g.mul(x_A);
          
     console.log('left x', left.getX().toString(16));
     console.log('left y', left.getY().toString(16));
     
     // H(ID_A, U_A) * U_A + R       
     const temp2 = U_A.mul(h_BigInt)
     const right = temp2.add(this.r_masterPublicKey); 
     console.log('right X:', right.getX().toString(16));
     console.log('right Y:', right.getY().toString(16));
}

Can anyone help? I don't know where I'm doing making an error..I couldn't find any library, which implements this scheme so I had to try it the manual way.

I'm sorry in order to make it more understandable i copied the code from one and forgot to change d to the this.masterPrivateKey. All my variables are defined and have a value which looks reasonable. I also changed the randBetween to the second version, which didn't help, also removing the -1 didn't help as well (and checking the number is below q). I could also use BigInt(this.q) to convert q, but it doesn’t make a difference, the number is still the same. Unfortunately I have to use JS.

It's set this.r_masterPublic and used this.r_masterPublicKey. Suggestion:: make this.q a BigInt right when it is extracted from this.ec.curve.n, rather than at the three places it's used later (and using multiple conversion methods). Log this.q in hex and check it against $n$ there. If that's not enough, also log h_BigInt, h_A, masterPrivateKey, x_A, and the coordinates of this.r_masterPublicKey, U_A, temp2. Check these values, or perhaps include them in the question (following the code, in the same block).

There is no doubt that whatever group noted additively with generator $G$ of order $q$, whatever non-negative integers $d$, $h_A$ and $h'_A$ (the later standing for $H(\mathsf{ID}_A,U_A)$), if we compute $R=d×G$, and $U_A=h_A×G$, and $x_A =(h'_A·h_A+d)\bmod q$, then it must hold $x_A×G=h'_A×U_A+R$. The question was closed because it is about some implementation issue, and on top of that we can't find it because we don't have reference for the elliptic library, and we do not have consistent code, nor a log of the intermediate values. Fell free to further improve the question, though.
